# Yahtzee game, __str__ not working

Tags: python

I realize I've been pretty much spamming this forum lately, I'm just trying to break my problems down since I'm supposed to create a yahtzee game for assignment. My code is currently looking like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.lista={"ones":0,"twos":0,"threes":0, "fours":0,"fives":0,"sixs":0,"abovesum":0,"bonus":0,"onepair":0,"twopair":0,"threepair":0,"fourpair":0,"smalladder":0,"bigladder":0,"house":0,"chance":0,"yatzy":0,"totalsum":0}
        self.spelarlista=[]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def welcome(self):
        print("Welcome to the yahtzee game!")
        players = int(input("How many players: "))
        rounds=0
        while not players==rounds:
            player=input("What is your name?: ")
            rounds=rounds+1
            self.spelarlista.append(Player(player))
            print(self.spelarlista)


def main():
    play=Player("Joakim")
    play.welcome()
    for key in ["names","ones","twos","threes","fours","fives","sixs","abovesum","bonus","onepair","twopair","threepair","fourpair","smalladder","bigladder","house","chance","yatzy","totalsum"]:
        print("%-20s"%key)


main()
```

My goal is that its gonna look something like this: https://gyazo.com/26f997ed05c92898d93adaf0af57d024

If you look at my method "welcome", I do want to print my self.spelarlista, just to see how its gonna look, but all I get is "Player object at 0x7fac824....", I realize something is wrong with my **str**, how should I change it?

Comment: We are not a code review site. Please expain the specific issue and show only that code.

Comment: Please remember you are asking for free help on the internet. It is **your job** to dig through **your code** and figure out where your error is happening, not ours! If you are posting **an entire program** on StackOverflow, I can 99% guarantee you that you have not done enough work up front to ask a question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I posted too much, I guess I posted all of my code because I'm a bit unsure if the problem is only with my __str__ or if it's something else. To next time I'll post less code.

Comment: That's the thing... you don't have the first clue where it is happening. Figuring that out is basic debugging and you're the only one who can do it right. If you don't know the answer to that question, you're not ready to post here. It's not even that we don't want to help you -- it's that we often can't. There's just too many variables that exist only on your computer. It's guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

When you print a list of objects python doesn't call the objects `__str__` method but the container list. If you want to print them all you can call the `__str__` method by applying the built-in function `str()` on them using `map()` or a list comprehension and join them with `str.join()` method.

```
print(' '.join(map(str, self.spelarlista)))
```

Or as another alternative approach you can define a [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) attribute for your objects, which returns the official string representation of an object:

```
>>> class A:
...    def __init__(self):
...        pass
...    def __repr__(self):
...       return 'a'
... 
>>> l = [A()]
>>> 
>>> print l
[a]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting `Player object at 0x7fac824` or anything similar, it seems that you are calling the `repr` on the object (indirectly), which in turn calls the object's `__repr__` method.

```
class Player:
    # ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    # ...
```

Since there is no `__str__` method defined, `__str__` will also default to calling `__repr__`.

`__repr__` returns a string representation of the object (usually one that can be converted back to the object, but that's just a convention) which is what you need.

Comment: Thank you Rushy Panchal and Kasramvd for helping out, your solutions did work!